# Handbrake: Best IPhone playable Settings for a 2:1 Aspect Ratio Video

Tags: video, resolution, iphone, video-conversion, handbrake

Original Video Settings (360 Panoramic video):
H264
Bitrate: 15000 kbps
FPS: 48
Resolution 3820 x 1910
My current settings in handbrake are:
Apple TV3 Preset
Width: 1920 
Height: none 
Anamorphic: Loose
Modulus: 2
Video Codec: H264
FPS:30
Quality: 20 RF
X264 preset: medium
x264 tune: none
H264 profile: baseline
H264 Level: 3.1

Whenever the screen resolution is not 1920xWidth, the video fails to display entirely on the Iphone.  What is the best way to maintain the best quality possible? I suspect the fix may be in the anamorphic settings, but after reading many resources on it, I am still haveing trouble understanding the concept.